Can I get translation of commentary regarding Gaudapada karika?
Can I get a translation of the non-English highlighted text?


Read a different book (translation by some other author) that did not use any non-English words.

https://www.amazon.in/Gaudapada-Advaita-Vedantas-First-Philosopher-ebook/dp/B00NFOAGC0

Can you please clarify what you are looking for? I could not understand your question.

@blue_ego. I can try but have no context. Why don't you try google lens and google translate since you would have read the remaining parts of this text too.

this def sounds polemic in nature, also slanderish but whatever, still interesting


Dharmas are not greater than knowledge.

Knowledge does not count among (is greater than) Dharma.

Dharmas are not born of the mind.

The mind is not born of dharma.

I will speak to you.

Debate of realizations.

External meaning.

This is not spoken by Buddha

Silence is the word of Buddha.

very nice. thank you.  that sounds interesting to me.

I think some of Buddha's following had realizations too  (transcribed in early Buddhist scripture, e.g. "nirvana is the end of existence") but he himself wasn't known to teach like that

The word vijnana by the way also means scientific knowledge. https://vedabase.io/en/search/synonyms/?original=vij%C3%B1%C4%81na

hmm..that makes sense, he denied the sixfold manifestation as self

Open to any corrections. The word for 'external meaning' is Bāhyārtha (बाह्यार्थ). You can read its meanings here: https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/bahyartha#sanskrit

I wonder what dharmas means here?  phenomena might not be accurate..i thought Buddha taught the mind was conditioned

translated as 'realization' seems enough...what is the transliteration you know?

Dharmas could be religions or principles. Transliteration of realization? It's VijnAna as mentioned above.

hmm..now a little confused, b/c denied the external, but admitted 'vijnana' seems redundant or clumsy...but 'realization' seems like a totally different interpretation

maybe one more favor if you are interested, just type the words of the Sanskrit terms like you did for बाह्यार्थ, i can't copy

r u saying 'realization' is sensory?  that would at least make sense

Realizations are usually beyond the five senses.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
